# Problem in regex pattern

Tags: excel

I have `[$-809]d mmmm yyyy;@`. This will print the date like this:

```
8 May 2010
```

but I want to print like this:

```
8 May
2010
```

I want the line break in this date. How can I do this?

Comment: well i am using it in Ms Exel

Comment: I cannot see why is this tagged regex though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tip found [here](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/forcing-carriage-return-in-custom-date-format/) : you can choose `Custom format` in the `Format Cell` menu. You can type the first part of the cell, say `d mmmm`, then type `Ctrl-J` and then the `yyyy` part.

Hope that helps,

Regards,

Max